# Where can I find an introduction to SSL with OpenSSL?

Tags: ssl, openssl, stunnel

I want to learn about the nuts-and-bolts of using SSL to secure client/server communication.  Is there any documentation, anywhere, regarding how to do this with OpenSSL?

The best I've been able to find so far is the source code for stunnel (http://www.stunnel.org/)...

To be more precise, I want the client to be able to connect with the server, do the secure handshake, verify that the the server's certificate is valid (eg, signed by a trusted CA, not expired, etc) then send some data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These look promissing:

http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/openssl.html

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-openssl.html

Comment: Awesome, the dev works article looks good.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've also found this: http://www.rtfm.com/openssl-examples/ which has good, simple examples.

Comment: Link is not working man...do you have another updated link ?